# increase number in Class CSS automatically

Tags: html

I want to make the following happen in:

There is a for loop generating images of a list. I still want to be capable of styling indiviual images with CSS, so I need to generate a unique Class for each element of the list.

Is there a way to generate a string like ("a") plus the generated number so that the result is a1, a2, a3, a4...(a.id)?

Lets say the list is 4 elements long.

```
<li *ngFor="let chair of chairs">  
    class="a + {{ chair.id }}"
</li>
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494458/how-to-add-class-as-per-number-of-iteration-in-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ignore the plus `+` sign and append the value directly.

```html
<li *ngFor="let chair of chairs" class="a{{ chair.id }}">
  ...
</li>
```

If for instance the `chair.id` values are 1, 2, 3,... then the rendered list would look like

```html
<li class="a1">...</li>
<li class="a2">...</li>
<li class="a3">...</li>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngClass
Although, in general, I don't recommend doing it like that.
You can use CSS `nth-child` for use case like that.

If you prefer doing it with ngClass the syntax is that

```
<li *ngFor="let chair of chairs" ngClass="a{{ chair.id }}">
  ...
</li>
```